# How to get information about identified point and exclude it in next plot in R

Tags: r

i've got problem with `identify()`.

I have something like this

```
library (UsingR)
df=data.frame(emissions)
plot (df)
getPoint=identify(df)
```

And I have to exclude the point  that is too far away from correct observation group.

How can I take this uncorrect point save it, exclude it, and get the correct frame in next plotting without saved point?

Answer (score 0):

First off I tried using `identify` on a data frame plot- it doesn't seem to work so instead I did one comparison- GDP vs perCapita:

```
plot(df$GDP,df$perCapita)
getPoint=identify(df$GDP,df$perCapita)
```

I then picked a few points on the plot and then pressed 'ESC'

`getPoint` returns the number of the row of the points that I picked. I can then omit or select these points:

```
df[getPoint,] #select picked data points
df[-getPoint,] #exclude picked data points
```

Comment: The point is that `getPoint` isn't getting any point. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Hi sorry I retried it with your dataset- it turns out you can't use `identify` on a multipanel plot (i.e. plotted dataframe) so I had to do it with one of the pairwise comparisons- see above.